# Approximate roots for Arbitrary-Degree Polynomial - two close roots

Tags: polynomials, roots

Here are two slides from Fundamentals of Power Electronics. When talking about approximation roots on n-th order polynomial $P(s)=1+a_1s+...+a_ns^n$ with the form of $P(s)=(1+\tau_1s)(1+\tau_2s)...(1+\tau_3s)$, it uses some math that I cannot figure out on myself.

Firstly, I'd like to show the result when every root separate with each other.

[image: slide1]

And here is the result if consider two close roots exists.

[image: slide2]

In the last step, I do not know why approximation is accurate leads to the last inequality. Could you give me some hint or explanation? Thanks.

---

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/159e3Ku3Tw6rDCsQhr66yYJ70oYPtmj_g/view?usp=sharing) is the original slide file.

Comment: in $P(x)=(1+t_1s)(1+t_2s)$... What is $t_i$?

Comment: @NoChance I'd like to describe $\tau_i$ as placeholders, or maybe unknwons, writing polynomial in the form of $P(x)=...(1+\tau_is)...$ then control theory results can be easily applied. When roots are separated, the result is $\tau_i{\approx}a_i/a_{i-1}$.

Comment: There must be a "root" for this formula somewhere....I am interested! I guess a good start for me would be to come up with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the special case first.
If the first equality is not satisfied, the slide say use this:

$P(s) ≈ (1+a_1s+a_2s^2)(1+{a_3 \over a_2}s)\cdots(1+{a_{n} \over a_{n-1}}s)$

Product of first two terms must approximate its underlying cubic:

$(1+a_1s+a_2s^2)(1+{a_3 \over a_2}s) ≈ 1 + a_1s+ a_2s^2 + a_3s^3$

$s^1$ coefficient: $|a_1| ≫ |{a_3 \over a_2}|$
$s^2$ coefficient: $|a_2| ≫ |{a_1 a_3 \over a_2}| → |{a_2^2 \over a_3}| ≫ |a_1| $

---

Use the same idea for the kth term, consider only the cubic:

$(1+ {a_{k-1} \over a_{k-2}}s)(1 + {a_k \over a_{k-1}}s + {a_{k+1} \over a_{k-1}}s^2) ≈ 1 + {a_{k-1} \over a_{k-2}}s + {a_{k} \over a_{k-2}}s^2 + {a_{k+1} \over a_{k-2}}s^3$

$s^1$ coefficient: $\large |{a_{k-1} \over a_{k-2}}| ≫ |{a_{k} \over a_{k-1}}|$
$s^2$ coefficient: $\large |{a_{k} \over a_{k-2}}| ≫ |{a_{k+1} \over a_{k-1}}| → |{a_{k} \over a_{k-1}}| ≫ |{a_{k-2}\; a_{k+1} \over a_{k-1}^2}|$